# live search on webpage without refreshing it

Tags: search, live

I know you can achieve it with php, mysql and ajax, but it reads the data from a database file, right ?
I'm thinking about how I should make small page with that. Should i place all my text, titles in the database or is there a way to do that inside of html structure ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put all the data inside the document, that would eventually make the website slow.

Store the data in a database and download it when typing in the search field. You can either send a request every *n* seconds using AJAX, or download and store all the data in f.e. localStorage and call that using AJAX.